# DateTime changing problem after deployment of asp.net mvc application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

all datetimes in my application increasing by 8 hours after publishing the app on the server.

this the datetime variable on localhost when I print it in console
*Thu Feb 20 2020 16:24:44 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)*

this is the same datetime variable on the server
*Fri Feb 21 2020 00:24:44 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)*

how can I prevent these changes

Comment: I suppose you are sure about your own timezone, but what of the server's? Isn't that UTC (although the offset doesn't seem to match)?

Answer (score 0):

Points to check to fix the issue

1. Check how to set your server time
2. If you are using a database, check the database engine time
3. Always try to use UTC based times (recommended)
4. Try to use the js library called 'moment' (recommended)